# How do I get a range validation?

Tags: python

Here is my text:

```
def judgeScoreInput():
if int(input()) in range (11) == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]:
  A = int(input("Enter Judge A Score: "))
  B = int(input("Enter Judge B Score: "))
  C = int(input("Enter Judge C Score: "))
  D = int(input("Enter Judge D Score: "))
  E = int(input("Enter Judge E Score: "))
judgeScoreInput()
```

I want the Judge score to have a range limit upon to 10 so user can't input more than 10, if they do it sends some sort if error message, how do I go about this?

Comment: you want a while loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of laying things out.  Note that I avoid code duplication as much as possible, and take advantage of recursion to "re-ask" when the input is invalid

```
def get_score(name):
    score = int(input('Enter score for Judge {}: '.format(name)))
    if score not in range(11): # Note that we can't assign input to a variable and check that variable at the same time
        print('Please enter an integer score 0-10')
        return get_score(name)
    return score

def judge_score_input():
    judges = {}
    for judge in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'):
        judges[judge] = get_score(judge)
    return judges
```

`judge_score_input` will return a dictionary mapping the letters `A`-`E` to scores.  In your original implementation, the local variables would have been discarded at the end of the function call.

Comment: thanks 4 ur answer, im new to this so I just pasted ur code into python and on the first line it came up with invalid syntax? what do I need to do to fix this

Comment: @AarronGrigg My bad, I missed a colon at the end of the first line.  Try the fixed version

Comment: I figured that bit but it returns with RESTART: and then my Mac info and also is blank when it runs.. any help is appreciated lol

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to this snippet of code.  If you can't figure it out you should consider asking another question.